# PHPUnit does not report on Not Successful Test

Tags: selenium, phpunit, logging, report

I've install PHPUnit3.6.2 and tried to run simple test.
If test Successful, there are no problems: phpunit reporting that test is OK.
But if there any error in test, PHPUnit reporting NOTHING! No failure and error text, no line in test.php, just empty line.

If it can helps: in browser code ends with `getLocation()` method. But I didnt use such method in my test.
why is this happening?

Also I should add: if in test use some element, wich not present on web page (for example button with wrong x-path). And there is action with this button in test:

```
$this->clickAt("wrong x-path");
```

phpunit doesn't show error report too. It continues to run. Looks like it found this button and clicked it. But there is NO such button on page.

No errors, no failures, test doesn't stop...

Comment: Things to check: a) is there a fatal error? b) are you calling `exit()`? c) is the test actually successful? It would really help of you pasted the full output of the test run including the PHPUnit version, time, and assertion count.

Comment: In addition to whats already been asked: Do you have error reporting set to the max and display error turned on in your php.ini because you run into a parser error

Comment: a) is there a fatal error? - there are no fatal errors in this test.
b) are you calling exit()? - why should I call exit()?
c) is the test actually successful? - this test was successful, but I added an assertion, wich is wront, because I want to check correct work of installed phpunit. On another computer this test runs correct And phpunit shows that there is a failure: "boolean:true is false".
Error reporting in my php.ini: 
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: b) If you have a call to `exit()` in your code or test, PHPUnit will exit without printing a summary. You should not call `exit()`--was just checking if you did. Again, the full output from PHPUnit will help us help you.

Comment: I'sorry, but i don't understand about wich "full output from PHPUnit" you ask me... can You explain more? Where can I get it? Because after test I can see only empty string in PHPUnit report.

Comment: @Evgeniya He wants to know what PHPUnit outputs after you run this test. I assume your terminal doesn't just keep hanging doing nothing and PHPUnit must say something.

Answer (score 2):

You are alking about Selenium testing. `getLocation()` is called by PHPUnit when formatting the failure report (to display the URL on which the failure occurred). You should try some simple (non-Selenium) PHPUnit tests to see if failure/error reporting works there, so you can narrow it down to Selenium or PHPUnit itself.